# How to interpolate multiple variables in a Markdown string in Julia

Tags: julia, markdown, string-interpolation

In the following Julia 1.5 code:

```
a, b = 4, 5
"a=$(a), b=($b)" # "a=4, b=5"
using Markdown
md"a=$(a), b=($b)" # a=a, b=b
# but...
Markdown.parse("a=$(a), b=($b)") # "a=4, b=5"
```

It seems that the Markdown macro thinks two `$` indicate a math expression. But the `parse` handles it OK.

Can someone explain this? is there a way to use the `md"..."` form for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious in my opinion, but I think `$` with a non-space before is interpreted as a closing LaTeX `$` if there is one before.

Some suggestions:

- If you're OK with spaces around your `=` sign, then this works:

  ```
  julia> md"a = $a, b = $b"
    a = 4, b = 5
  ```
- Or you could make it a list:

  ```
  julia> md"""
         - a=$a
         - b=$b
         """
      •    a=4

      •    b=5
  ```